# Multiple Layouts with few repetitive views (here & there so, cannot use <include>) versus Fewer layouts with hidden views

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I am not sure if this is even a question worth asking or I am just bit too much overworked to think through this hence, the community help would surely be great at this stage to resolve this issue.

So, my question is that I have some 20-25 screens in my Android app. The app overall comprises of navigation drawer, tabstrips, fragments and lists in most of those fragments (some fragments only have listviews while some fragments have several other components and listviews as well). Now, few of these listviews have slightly similar row views but, not such that I could use the tag "include" due to placement and size issues.

For example, in rowview_1, I have one imageview (ImageView_1) and three textviews (TextView_1, TextView_2, TextView_3) to its right and finally, an imageview (ImageView_2) on extreme right on whose click an event occurs. Whereas, in rowview_2, I have one imageview (ImageView_1) and three textviews (TextView_1, TextView_2, TextView_3) to its right. On extreme right, two more textviews which convey some extra info and an imageview (ImageView_2) beside ImageView_1 and below TextView_3.

So, what would be a better and optimized approach in such a scenario?
1) Having separate multiple rowview layouts
2) Having one rowview with all the static elements in one place and dynamically adding and removing the extra elements (I believe it could be equally expensive for a rowview in a listview).

I am not sure if there can be any other approach. Any idea/guidance is most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. I think the differences if there are any are very minimal.

Scenario 1:
1) Cleaner code
2) Easier to make changes to one without affecting the other.

Scenario 2:
1) Complicated layout file
2) Does not necessarily take longer to load if everything's visibility is set to GONE in the layout.

One thing to note is that if you are going to load both layouts in the same Activity, you should surely go with scenario 2. When you load it the first time, the activity caches the layout so the next time, it loads super fast. If they are split over different activity, then the cache is gone anyways. Another thing to consider is how often you make changes to both together. If that is going to be often then scenario 2 is better. Changes will be done in one file. I personally prefer scenario 1. Its easier to show someone else who wants to make changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yeah, it surely helped. I am inclined to scenario 1 too for the cleaner code and freedom of making changes later, as the app evolves. But, lets see if any other idea/approach appears. PS: Due to lack of sufficient reputation, I cannot upvote your answer

Comment: As there is no further response so, I would accept this answer only.